# PHP if else not working when use multi variable with OR

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I have laravel blade template that use if else to show the alert.

here my code

```
@if($foo = Request('foo') and ($bar = Request('bar')))
    Search result for: <strong>{{ $foo }} and {{ $bar }}
@endif
```

on my code above

it's working if both forms filled. but when one of them form empty its print nothing.

how to make it if one or both filled its return like :

one form filled.

```
Search result for: Keyword
```

both form filled.

```
Search result for: Keyword and category
```

Comment: cause you are using `and` try changing that to `OR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `and` to denote that both fields must be entered. While just an `or` could suffice, this will have the problem that the extra field will be outputted. To correct this, you'll want independent outputs for when **either** field is entered, outputting the relevant field. Then you'll want another output for when **both** fields are entered.

If you have the condition for both fields as the main `@if` conditional, it won't be entered into when only field is set, so you can use `@elseif` for the other two outputs:

```
@if($foo = Request('foo') and ($bar = Request('bar')))
    Search result for: <strong>{{ $foo }} and {{ $bar }}
@endif

@elseif($foo = Request('foo'))
    Search result for: <strong>{{ $foo }}
@endif

@elseif($bar = Request('bar'))
    Search result for: <strong>{{ $bar }}
@endif
```

Comment: yes, use `or` also got a problem. I think I will use independent outputs for either field.